# Why is 1920 device-independent units not 1920 pixel with 96 DPI?

Tags: wpf, screen-resolution, dpi

My Windows settings are set to have a DPI of 96. However when I create the following `Window` it will be a little smaller then my screen (which is set to the resolution 1920*1080):

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_Sandbox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_Sandbox"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="1920">
</Window>
```

According to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/text/2009/12/11/wpf-text-measurement-units/) msdn blog post:

> 1 device independent pixel = 1/96 inch.
> 1 physical pixel = 1/DPI (dependent on the system DPI)
>
> Default system settings usually choose a DPI of 96 so these two types of pixels come out to be the same size.

However this does not seem to be the case since my `Window` is clearly less then 1920 pixel wide.
If I maximize the `Window` and inspect its `ActualWidth` it appears to be `1936`.

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question is more along the lines of:

> Why does Window.ActualWidth report a width that does not appear to be the 'real' width of the Window?

The answer is that what *looks like* the full width of the window isn't exactly the *full* width.

When you set the `Width`, query the `ActualWidth`, or even use `GetWindowRect` to get the "no-lies what does windows think my width is", you're setting or getting the width of the Window including *invisible parts*.

Those invisible parts, especially on Windows 10, includes a little bit of extra space for making it easy for users to resize the window even if they're a little bit off of the border:

[image: resize off of the window]

(note that my mouse is not on the border but rather a bit off to the right)

This means that when you maximize your window, your width is still "padded" with that invisible space, and thus your window size will be bigger than your screen size.

How can you retrieve the width of the extra space? [`GetSystemMetrics`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385(v=vs.85).aspx) with `SM_CXSIZEFRAME` and `SM_CXPADDEDBORDER` is your friend here (example includes code from [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums.SystemMetric)):

```
int extraBorderStuff = GetSystemMetrics(SystemMetric.SM_CXSIZEFRAME)
                       + GetSystemMetrics(SystemMetric.SM_CXPADDEDBORDER);
double realWidthForSure = ActualWidth - borderSize * 2;
```

If you then maximize your window, you should notice that `realWidthForSure` should equal your 1920px that you'd expect.

Comment: So basically, when I maximize the `Window` it will be bigger than the screen (therefore `Width` is `1936`) because of the invisible border. Gotcha.

Comment: @TimPohlmann yes; added a little bit more to the answer to state that.

Answer (score 3):

The window really has a width of 1936 pixels!

When a window is maximized, the border around it is cropped. Although it is not visible any more, it is still considered part of the window. In the Aero theme, this border has a width of 8px on each side, hence the 16px extra:

[image: Window chrome in Aero theme]

If you switch to the Classic theme, it's only 4px on each side, so your window would be 1928 pixels wide.

Comment: But my screen only has 1920 pixels.

Comment: The window is wider than your screen.

Comment: But it is not. There is space left on both sides.

Comment: It would help if you added a screen shot to your question.

Comment: I got it figured out. You are basically right. It's just very confusing in Windows 10 because there is an invisible window border.

Answer (score -1):

What are your screen specs? for e.g. my monitor has pitch = 0.282 mm; which equals to 90.0709... ppi. A 1920 pixels wide window would have actual width of 2,046 units in WPF.

determine your screen's DPI (25.4/pitch if you have pitch in mm)

96/DPI * 1920 => Actual Width

Comment: How does WPF know the physical DPI of my monitor? According to the linked blog post it uses the system DPI of Windows, which is set to 96.